# CSS color child on Hover

Tags: css, hover, parent

i got this:

```
<div id="father">
    <span class="child1"><span>
    <div class="child2"><div>
</div>
```

i need to change text color of child2 on father:hover, and i was able to do that, 
but when i hover on child1, child2 loose color and is displayed normally, how can i set hover on child1 so do not loose hover effect ?

i've already tried with and it doesn't work

```
.child1:hover .child2{ color: #eed847; }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.child1` is not a parent of `.child2` in your example, which is expected by your use of space in the selector.

The following selector should work, when any of `.child1` or `.child2` is hovered.

```
#father:hover .child2 { ... }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w4rKh/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the text color of the second child to change you could use a workaround like this:

```
#father:hover .child2 {color: #eed847;}
.child2:hover {color: #000!important;}
```

In this example the text of `child2` will stay black when you only hover over `child2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sibling selector in your CSS, [Chris Coyier has written a fair bit about them here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

```
.child1:hover + .child2 { #some css };
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing tags of HTML were invalid. I modifed your HTML and added css for your needed behaviour.

**HTML**

```
<div id="father"> <span class="child1">child1</span>
    <div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#father {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: green;
}
.child2, #father span.child1:hover + div.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#father:hover .child2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/eE3Dm/1/)**